# Как у ссылки удалить <a> и оставить только текст?

Tags: jquery

Есть ссылка вида:

```
<a data-id='5' href='/example'>Text</a>
```

Мне же нужно чтобы вместо нее на странице было только `Text`.

Ссылки я перебираю и работаю с каждой. Я пробовал так:

```
$(this).removeAttr("href");
```

Но в итоге остается:

```
<a data-id='5'>Text</a>
```

А нужно:

```
 Text
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').replaceWith(function () {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('a').prop('innerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id='5' href='/example'>Text</a>
```

```js
console.log($('a').text())
console.log($('a').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id='5' href='/example'>Text</a>
```